# animate border property on any element in one complete round css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to animate border-property on below html element having different shapes like rectangle, square, circle etc:-

The animation looks like:- it should start drawing border from one corner and stops at the last corner to complete one rotation.

## html

```css
.rectangle{
 width:50px;
 height:25px;
 border:1px solid #333;  //animate this property 
}
.square{
 width:40px;
 height:40px;
 border:1px solid #333;   //animate this property 
}

.circle {
width:50px;
height:50px;
border: 1px solid #333; 
border-radius:100%;
}

.marg-T{
margin-top:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="rectangle"></div>
<div class="circle marg-T"></div>
<div class="square marg-T"></div>
```

Comment: You can find an example here on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/animating-border/)

Comment: The question is about to draw border around element starting from one corner to another corner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CSS animation:

```css
@keyframes fade {
  0%   {border: 1px solid black;}
  25%  {border-left: 1px solid white;}
  50%  {border-left: 1px solid white;border-top: 1px solid white;}
  75%  {border-left: 1px solid white;border-top: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid white;}
  100% {border-left: 1px solid white;border-top: 1px solid white;border-right: 1px solid white;border-bottom: 1px solid white;}
}

#circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  animation: fade 4s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle"></div>
```

, although this fades it and doesn't stay afterwards, it still is a start. I doubt there being a pure CSS way to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample code for animated border. Please have a look and let me know if this helps.

HTML

```
 <div className="box-b">
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <span></span>
           <div className="content-b">
             <h1>Let's Connect</h1>
             <div className="contact-content" >
              <form className="Message-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        
                <p>Name</p>
                <input name="name" onChange={this.handleInput} ></input>
                <br></br>
                <p>Message</p>
                <textarea onChange={this.handleInput} name="message" className="message-input" ></textarea>
                <br></br>
                <p>Email</p>
                <input onChange={this.handleInput} name="email" ></input>
                <br></br>
                <button  type="submit" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="send" >Send</button>
            
              </form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box-b{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  /* background:#E3E3E3; */
 
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow:hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 30px 50px rgba(82, 78, 78, 0.5);
  /* border:2px solid aqua; */


}
.box-b:before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  transform: 0.5; 
  pointer-events: none;


}
/* .box:hover:before{
  left: -50%;
  transform: skewX(-5deg)
} */
.box-b .content-b{
  position: absolute;
  top:15px;
  left:15px;
  right: 15px;
  bottom: 15px;
  border: 2px solid aqua;

  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);

}
.box-b .content-b h1{
  color:white;;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0;


}
.box-b .content-b p{
  color: white;
}

.box-b span{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;

}
.box-b span:nth-child(1){
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}
.box-b span:nth-child(2){
  transform: rotate(90deg)
}
.box-b span:nth-child(3){
  transform: rotate(180deg)
}
.box-b span:nth-child(4){
  transform: rotate(270deg)
}

.box-b span:nth-child(2):before{
  animation-delay: -2s;
}
.box-b span:nth-child(2):before{
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.box-b span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #ff1100;
  animation: animate1 2s linear infinite;



}
@keyframes animate1{
  0%{
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: left;

  }
  50%{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;

  }
  50.1%{
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: right

  }
  100%{
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transform-origin: right;

  }
}
```

Live working Version https://sheltered-refuge-69000.herokuapp.com/contact